# Spinor tensor multiplication rules

Tags: spinors, clifford-algebra

I’m wondering how to contract a product of gamma matrices like

$$(\gamma^5)_b^{~~d}(\gamma^5\gamma^{\mu})_{ad}$$

Is this just $$(\gamma^5)_b^{~~d}(\gamma^5\gamma^{\mu})_{ad} = (\gamma^5\gamma^5\gamma^{\mu})_{ab}$$

Or have I slaughtered the algebra? Help much appreciated

Comment: Do you mean if the $\textbf{a}$ and $\textbf{d}$ were swapped, it’d make the result representation independent?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Okay, so my understanding is that $(\gamma^{\mu})_{ab}= (\gamma^{\mu})_{ba}$ and $(\gamma^5 \gamma^{\mu})_{a}^{~~c}C_{cb}=-(\gamma^5 \gamma^{\mu})_{b}^{~~c}C_{ca}$ Is there no analogous way to swap indices on a product of gamma matrices (maybe picking up a minus sign)?

Comment: For example, can I use the fact that $\{\gamma^{5},\gamma^{\nu}\}=0$ to say that $(\gamma^5 \gamma^{\nu})_{bc}= -(\gamma^5 \gamma^{\nu})_{cb} $

Comment: The statement $(\gamma^\mu)_{ab}= (\gamma^\mu)_{ba}$ has to be representation dependent. In general $C\gamma^\mu C^{-1} =- (\gamma^\mu)^T$.

Comment: This is D=4 N=1 SUSY. Where do people usually pick up this kind of calculation of gamma matrices with spinor indices?